# How to setup jsoup

Tags: jsoup

This is embarassing for me to ask, but how do i setup jsoup. I use dreamweaver but can figure out how to get jsoup to work. Do i need another program to go with it. im completely fustrated please help.

Answer (score 4):

It's just like any other Java library.  It needs to be on your classpath then start using it!

```
Document doc = Jsoup.parse(html);
```

or

```
Document doc = Jsoup.connect("http://www.example.com").get();
```

Comment: I've found out what i was missing. Something to run the lirary on. I thought i could use Dreamweaver but after searching i came across something called Eclipse. Is Eclipse a good choice.What do u Suggest.

Comment: Yes, Eclipse is very good.  So, it sounds like you don't know much about Java development?  You'll need Java to run Jsoup.

Comment: Thank you so much. Your right i dont know much about java but thats about to change.

Answer (score 0):

there are 2 major platforms you can use Java on and that is Eclipse and Netbeans. I personally prefer Netbeans because of UX and availability to code online but Eclipse is also good for easier transition between different comp. languages.

Anyway, once you have Netbeans or Eclipse, download java jdk. You can find more on how to install these platforms from Youtube tutorials.

Then if you want jSoup you will have to download it from their webiste (fairly simple right?) and in option of your platform (Netbeans/Eclipse) you will navigate to libraries and link your downloaded .JAR file to your studio. That's it. Then you can start using jSoup. For more details on each step use google. I do not provide links because this is pretty simple and I suppose you needed guidence more than steps.

Byee